# Android Application is not compatible for new devices on play store

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

My Application is not supported
for new android devices versions: Your device is not comptaible with this version.
my manifest File is: All permission and Screen Sizes.android manifest file

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            package="com.fs.android.application" >
            //permissions
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" android:required="false"  />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false"  />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="false"  />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="false" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="false" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="false" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:required="false" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:required="false" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:required="false" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" android:required="false" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.CAMERA" android:required="false" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi.direct" android:required="false" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" />
            //Device screen size
            <compatible-screens>
                <!-- all small size screens -->
                <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
                <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
                <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
                <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
                <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
                <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
                <!-- all normal size screens -->
                <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
                <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
                <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
                <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
                <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
                <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
                <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
                <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
                <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
                <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
                <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
                <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
                <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
                <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
                <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
                <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
                <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
                <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
            </compatible-screens>
            //screen size
            <supports-screens
                android:smallScreens="true"
                android:normalScreens="true"
                android:largeScreens="true"
                android:xlargeScreens="true"
                />
            </application>
        </manifest>
}
```

build.gradle: all libraries and SDK version.android gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
        //compile sdk
        compileSdkVersion 30
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.fs.android.application"
            //minimum sdk
            minSdkVersion 18
            //target sdk version
            targetSdkVersion 30
            versionCode 5
            versionName "5"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                debug {
                    debuggable false
                }
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
        // google support library ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        //implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
        // third party dependencies -------------------------------------------------------------------
        implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2' // ripple effect
        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0' // image loader
        implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.2.0' // date & time picker
        implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0' // circle image view
        implementation 'com.github.pchmn:MaterialChipsInput:1.0.5' // material chip
        implementation 'com.hootsuite.android:nachos:1.1.1' // material chips
        implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.2' // google flexible box
        implementation 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.3' // range seek bar
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
        implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.5'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
        //implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0"
        //implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0' // dependency file for RecyclerView
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext:library:0.0.6'
        implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
        implementation 'com.github.chivorns:smartmaterialspinner:1.0.4'
        implementation 'com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext:library:0.0.6'
        implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
        implementation 'com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext:library:0.0.6'
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.3.0'
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
        //implementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
        implementation group: 'commons-io',
        name: 'commons-io',
        version: '2.4'
    }
```

Comment: check merged manifest - maybe some library adding something ... also why you are touching `compatible-screens` and `supports-screens` at all?

Comment: Why exactly do you have a debug tag in the release build types?

Comment: i remove but not resolve

Comment: support version 10 and so many mobile support but samsung and xiaomi mobile is not supported because notch camera .

Answer (score 0):

To fix the “your device is not compatible with this version” error message, try clearing the Google Play Store cache and storage, then restart the Google Play Store app and try installing the app again.

1. Launch the Settings app
2. Go to "Apps" or "App Manager"
3. Find "Google Play Store"
4. Select "Storage and Cache"
5. Clear both the Storage as well as the Cache
6. Launch the Google Play Store app again